# Messages queuing with PHP client and permanent DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, message-queue

I try to build an application where my web app will push some messages to a queue and then worker will extract messages and execute some SQL queries to remote DB.

There are couple good solutions, like gearman.org, rabbitMQ, etc.

**The problem** i got is how to keep a permanent connection to remote DB for all messages.
I don't want my worker reconnect to a DB each time when new SQL must be executed.

Is there a way to use one of good MQ systems and have some permanent worker or connection keept somewhen in shared memory ?
A worker must not be PHP, can be anything that connects to remote mysql server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I achieved the same on my SMS website is make a processor application on C# (luckily I have a windows server, you can do the same processor on a java app if you are using linux), and this processor will process the information using one connection and maybe with multi threading. It gives you complete control over the structure of the whole application from a processing point-of-view.

**Solution 1:**
Use a PHP worker/queue processor and run it through command line and keep it alive inside a while loop. Example:

php_file.php

```
<?php 
//create connection
while (true){
    //do the processing here
    sleep(3000);
}
?>
```

on cli, write:

```
nohup php php_file.php > worker_output.out &
```

**Solution 2:**
Write a program in any other language that does not ends the session once execute unlike PHP. Maybe python or java could help.